# Building a retaining wall with dense concrete blocks, best way to lay each course?

Tags: walls, construction, retaining-wall, concrete-block

I've seen a few walls that use the top method versus the more common stretcher/running bond, are there any benefits to doing it the first way?

[image: So I've seen a few walls that use the top method versus the more common stretcher bond, are there any benefits to doing it the first way?]

Comment: How tall is the wall going to be? Will it be mortared or dry fit?

Comment: 1m and it will be mortared

Comment: #1 is better than a stack bond I guess but the popularity of #2 isn't an accident...

Comment: https://www.gobrick.com/docs/default-source/read-research-documents/technicalnotes/30-bonds-and-patterns-in-brickwork.pdf?sfvrsn=0 seems resourceful

Answer (score 2):

use the first way only if you like the way it looks, stretcher bond is stronger.